# If Else, Case, or somethng else

Tags: t-sql

my query needs to show only students who are enrolled. Each student has several enrollment dates. If one of these enrollment dates is a drop out date they should not be included in the results. My columns are, StudentNumber, enrollment date, Action. If they drop out, they will have a "D" under action. I'm not sure how to filter out the drop out students since each one has multiple dates. Should I use an If Else or Case statement or maybe something in the where clause. If anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far?  Can you show sample data and desired results?

Comment: What is your schema?  If each student has several enrollment dates, do you have a join table of students to enrollment actions?

Comment: Dates and actions are together on one table. And if there is a drop out date, it isn't necessarily the MAX or current date either.

Comment: Rather than trying to describe things in comments, could you edit your question to make it clearer?  Any SQL you've attempted would also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hard to do without a better idea of your schema, but something like this may work for you:

```
SELECT e1.* FROM Enrollments e1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT StudentNumber FROM Enrollments
    WHERE Action = "D") dropped ON dropped.StudentNumber = e1.StudentNumber
WHERE dropped.StudentNumber IS NULL
```